# React native maps callout press not triggering on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react native maps and I'm trying to add en event listener when a marker callout is pressed. It works on Android but not on IOS. In this first snippet *calloutPress* gets called on Android but not on IOS:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    rotateEnabled={false}
    mapType="standard"
    initialRegion={region} 
>
    <Marker coordinate={markerCoordinate} onCalloutPress={() => this.calloutPress()}>
        <Callout>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>My title</Text>
                <Text style={styles.calloutDescription}>My description</Text>
            </View>
        </Callout>
    </Marker>
</MapView>
```

I also tried a touchable opacity inside the callout, now *calloutPress* is not called either on Android or IOS:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    rotateEnabled={false}
    mapType="standard"
    initialRegion={region}
>
    <Marker coordinate={markerCoordinate}>
        <Callout>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.calloutPress()}>
                <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>My title</Text>
                <Text style={styles.calloutDescription}>My description</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Callout>
    </Marker>
</MapView>
```

Here's the full class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker, Callout, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

export default class MapTabs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
                <MapView
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style={styles.map}
                    rotateEnabled={false}
                    mapType="standard"
                    initialRegion={region}
                >
                    <Marker coordinate={markerCoordinate}>
                        <Callout>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.calloutPress()}>
                                <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>My title</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.calloutDescription}>My description</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </Callout>
                    </Marker>
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );
    }

    calloutPress() {
        console.log("hello!");
    }
}

const region = {
    latitude: 54.403664,
    longitude: 14.769657,
    latitudeDelta: 30,
    longitudeDelta: 30
};

const markerCoordinate = { latitude: 54.403664, longitude: 14.769657 };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mapContainer: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        zIndex: 0
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1
    },
    calloutTitle: {
        fontSize: 17,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    calloutDescription: {
        fontSize: 14
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some additional research I found this open issue https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2223

The issue states that using provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} and a custom style on MapView is making onCalloutPress not trigger on IOS. It does trigger when using native provider.

Apparently there's an onPress event on the callout and using that makes it work on IOS as well. Here's a final solution working on both android and ios with google provider, it only trigger once on each platform:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker, Callout, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

export default class MapTabs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
                <MapView
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style={styles.map}
                    rotateEnabled={false}
                    mapType="standard"
                    initialRegion={region}
                >
                    <Marker
                        coordinate={markerCoordinate}
                        onCalloutPress={() => this.calloutPress()}
                    >
                        <Callout onPress={() => this.calloutPress()}>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>My title</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.calloutDescription}>My description</Text>
                            </View>
                        </Callout>
                    </Marker>
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );
    }

    calloutPress() {
        console.log("hello!");
    }
}

const region = {
    latitude: 54.403664,
    longitude: 14.769657,
    latitudeDelta: 30,
    longitudeDelta: 30
};

const markerCoordinate = { latitude: 54.403664, longitude: 14.769657 };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mapContainer: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        zIndex: 0
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1
    },
    calloutTitle: {
        fontSize: 17,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    calloutDescription: {
        fontSize: 14
    }
});
```

If you don't want to add event listeners that aren't triggered, make the onPress and onCalloutPress platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MapView.Callout`

Could you try this?

```js
export default class MapTabs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    calloutPress() {
        console.log("hello!");
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.map}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          mapType="standard"
          initialRegion={region}
        >
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={markerCoordinate}
          >
            <MapView.Callout>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.calloutPress()}
              >
                 <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>My title</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.calloutDescription}>My description</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </MapView.Callout>
          </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the same function binding I use everywhere else in my app and it works great. Tried this but no difference.

Comment: MapView.Callout is excactly the same as Callout when importing it from react-native-maps as I do. Tried this as well but still no luck.

Comment: I know that, but this may vary depending on the version. Could you try with `MapView.Marker` ?

Comment: Like my updated answer. These attempts can give you a solution.

Comment: What's your react-native-maps version?

Comment: Oh, there was a mistake. I didn't erase Marker's `onPress` from the answer.

Comment: I finally found a solution (see my answer), it was due to an issue in react-native-maps. And apparently there's an onPress event on the Callout which worked instead =) . Thanks for somewhat pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This module seems to have several problems with iOS. I'm glad it's settled.